# Drawing a multi column table

Tags: tables, positioning

I'm trying to create the table in the figure.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\begin{table*}[ht]

% \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
% \resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{%
\resizebox{17.5cm}{6.9cm}{%
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|lllll|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Paper}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Scope}} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\textbf{Topics}}                                                                                                                               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Contribution}}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Drawbacks}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Year}}} \\ \cline{3-7}
                                &                                 &  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Architecture Design}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Mobility}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Security}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Privacy}} & {\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Detection and Prevention}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                                       &                                       &                                \\ \hline
              \textit{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{\cite{139}}} }            & \textbullet VFC environment                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{55}}        &  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{55}}        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbullet VFC architecture \\ \textbullet Security issues in VFC \end{tabular}                                                                                    &    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbullet Security solutions  in VFC\end{tabular}                                   & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{2019}                           \\ \hline
\textit{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{\cite{142}} }}                          &  \textbullet VEC environment                               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{55}}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}        &    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{55}}                      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbullet V2V and V2I in VEC \\ \textbullet Security and privacy in VEC \end{tabular}   
          &    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbullet VFC and VEC comparison \\ \textbullet VEC security requirements \end{tabular}                                     & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{2019}                           \\ \hline
\textit{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{\cite{143}} } }                           & \textbullet FC in VANET                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{55}}        &   \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{55}}                        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbullet Connecting vehicles to VANET\\ \textbullet Security and forensics \\ requirements  \end{tabular}                                                             &   \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbullet Vehicles as Fog nodes \\ \textbullet Possible scenarios in VFC \\ \textbullet Detection and prevention in VFC  \end{tabular}                                    & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{2017}                           \\ \hline

\textit{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{\cite{146}} }}                &    \textbullet VFC application                             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{55}}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{55}}        &     \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{55}}                      & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbullet VFC : Video crowd-sourcing  \\ as a study case     \end{tabular}                                                              &  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbullet Security and privacy challenges \\ \textbullet Countermeasures for mitigation \\  in VFC  \end{tabular}                                     & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{2018}                           \\ \hline

\textit{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{\cite{149}} }}                 &    \textbullet FC in VANET                            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{55}}                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{55}}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}        &   \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{55}}                        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbullet Integration of FC in VANET     \end{tabular}                                                             &   \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbullet Deployment on vehicles as \\ fog nodes \\  \textbullet VFC applications     \end{tabular}                                     & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{2017}                           \\ \hline

\textit{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{\cite{145}}} }               &       \textbullet 
 VFC challenges                            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}        &   \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{55}}                       & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbullet VFC taxonomy \\ vehicles deployment in VFC     \end{tabular}                                                            &   \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbullet VFC implementation requirements \\ \textbullet Detection and \\prevention  in VFC  \end{tabular}                                     & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{2020}                           \\ \hline

\textit{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{\cite{147}} } }                 &  \makecell{\textbullet Dissemination of \\ Data in VFC}                         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{55}}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{55}}        &  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{55}}                         & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} VCC vs VFC in: \\ \textbullet Data Dissemination \\ \textbullet Applications \\ \textbullet Security threats   \end{tabular}                                                              &   \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbullet Privacy issues in VFC \\ \textbullet Misbehaving detection and\\ prevention  solutions   \end{tabular}                                     & \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{2021}                           \\ \hline

\textit{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\textbf{Our \\ \textbf{survey} } }}              &   \textbullet VFC                              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}         & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}        &  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\ding{51}}                         &  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbullet VFC global architecture  \\ \textbullet VFC implementation \\ \textbullet VFC  scenarios \\ \textbullet Security and privacy threats \\ \textbullet Detection and prevention  in VFC   \end{tabular}                                                            &                                       &                            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
}
\caption{Related Surveys Comparison}
\label{tab: RelatedSurveys}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: avoid resizing tables, certainly never do `\resizebox{17.5cm}{6.9cm}` that is scaling by different arbitrary amounts in each direction so will produce unreadably distorted text with no warning.  Please always post code as a complete example document so we do not have to guess definitions for non standard commads such as `\ding` and know the page size,

Comment: also `\begin{table*}[ht]` ,`table*` does not have an `h` option, but the table is probably too big for `[t]` so this is forcing it to the end of the document: omit the `[ht]` so the default positons including `p` for a float page for this table are allowed.

Comment: Any news? Does one of received answer solve your problem on the best (desired) way? If yes, please accept them (by clicking on the check mark at top left side of selected answer). If no one fulfil your requirements, than please clarify what is your problem!

Answer (score 3):

The following solution employs a `tabularx` environment and employs the `X` column type for 2 of the 10 columns. It also employs a bespoke itemize-like environment for items in the 2 X-type columns. Note that I've deleted virtually all `\multicolumn{1}{l|}{...}` wrapper since they do nothing except create considerable code clutter.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{rotating,multirow,makecell,tabularx,pifont}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters as needed
\newcommand\rx[1]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\usepackage{enumitem,ragged2e}
%% create a bespoke itemize-like environment:
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myitemize,1]{nosep, label=\textbullet, left=0pt,
          before={\strut\RaggedRight\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},
          after =\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| *{7}{l|} X | X | l |}
\hline

\multirow{2.5}{*}{\rx{Paper}} & 
Scope & 
\multicolumn{5}{c|}{Topics} & 
Contribution & 
Drawbacks & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rx{Year}} \\ 
\cline{3-7}
 &  &  
\rx{Architect.\ Design} & 
\rx{Mobility} & 
\rx{Security} & 
\rx{Privacy} & 
\rx{~Detect.\ and Prev.~} & & & \\ 
\hline
\rx{\cite{139}} & 
VFC env. & 
\ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} & \ding{55} & 
\begin{myitemize}
  \item VFC architecture  
  \item Security issues in VFC 
\end{myitemize}   &    
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Security solutions in VFC
\end{myitemize} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rx{2019}} \\ 
\hline
\rx{\cite{142}}  &  
VEC env. & 
\ding{51} & \ding{55} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} & 
\begin{myitemize}
  \item V2V and V2I in VEC 
  \item Security and privacy in VEC 
\end{myitemize}  &    
\begin{myitemize}
  \item VFC and VEC comparison 
  \item VEC security requirements 
\end{myitemize} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rx{2019}} \\ 
\hline
\rx{\cite{143}} & 
FC in VANET & 
\ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} & \ding{55} & 
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Connecting vehicles to VANET
  \item Security and forensics requirements  
\end{myitemize} &   
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Vehicles as Fog nodes 
  \item Possible scenarios in VFC 
  \item Detection and prevention in VFC  
\end{myitemize} & 
\multirow{3}{*}{\rx{2017}} \\ 
\hline
\rx{\cite{146}}  &    
VFC application  & 
\ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} & \ding{55} & \ding{55} & 
\begin{myitemize}
  \item VFC : Video crowd-sourcing 
  as a study case     
\end{myitemize} &  
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Security and privacy challenges 
  \item Countermeasures for mitigation in VFC  
\end{myitemize} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rx{2018}} \\ 
\hline
\rx{\cite{149}} &    
FC in VANET & 
\ding{55} & \ding{55} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} & 
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Integration of FC in VANET 
\end{myitemize}   &   
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Deployment on vehicles as fog nodes 
  \item VFC applications     
\end{myitemize} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rx{2017}} \\ 
\hline
\rx{\cite{145}}  &       
VFC challenges & 
\ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} & 
\begin{myitemize}
  \item VFC taxonomy vehicles deployment in VFC     
\end{myitemize}  &   
\begin{myitemize}
  \item VFC implementation requirements 
  \item Detection and prevention in VFC  
\end{myitemize}  & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rx{2020}} \\ 
\hline
\rx{\cite{147}}   &  
\makecell[t]{Dissemination of \\ Data in VFC} & 
\ding{51} & \ding{55} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} & \ding{55} & 
  VCC vs VFC in: 
  
  \begin{myitemize} 
  \item Data Dissemination 
  \item Applications 
  \item Security threats   
\end{myitemize} &   
\begin{myitemize}
  \item Privacy issues in VFC 
  \item Misbehaving detection and prevention solutions   
\end{myitemize} & 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rx{2021}} \\ 
\hline
\multirow{5}{*}{\rx{Our survey}}  &   
VFC   & 
\ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} &  
\begin{myitemize}
  \item VFC global architecture 
  \item VFC implementation
  \item VFC scenarios 
  \item Security and privacy threats
  \item Detection and prevention in VFC   
\end{myitemize} & & \\ 
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Related Surveys Comparison}
\label{tab: RelatedSurveys}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With use of the `tabularray`, `\rotating`, `makecell` (last two are for rotate cell contents) and `enumitem` packages. For better cell filling is reduced font size and `\linespread` in table cells. Using them are improved table looks, simplified table body code, however this are paid with longer compilation time as well table preamble is a bit more complex:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{rotating,
            makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\RaggedRight}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                      itemsep=0.5ex,
                      leftmargin=*}
    \small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont,
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\small}

\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {Q[c, m]
                        X[0.6, c, m]
                        *{5}{Q[c, wd=2em]}
                        *{2}{X[c, h]}
                        Q[c]
                        },
             colsep  = 3pt,
             cell{1}{1,Z}   = {r=2}{f,cmd=\renewcommand\theadalign{bl}
                                          \settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Paper}       
                                          \rothead},        % <---
             cell{1}{2,X-Z} = {r=2}{f},                     % <---
             cell{3-Y}{Z} = {cmd=\settowidth\rotheadsize{2020}\rothead},
             row{2}  = {cmd=\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
                            \settowidth\rotheadsize{\theadfont Detection and}
                            \rothead},
             rowsep  = 4pt,
             measure = vbox,
             stretch = -1,
             }
Paper
    &   Scope 
        &   \SetCell[c=5]{c}    Topics
            &   &   &   &   &   Contribution
                                &   Drawbacks
                                    &   Year    \\
    &   & Architecture Design
            & Mobility
                & Security
                    & Privacy
                        & Detection and Prevention
                            &   &   &           \\
{[14]}    %\cite{139}
    & VFC environment 
        & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} & \ding{55} 
            &   \begin{itemize}
            \item VFC architecture
            \item Security issues in VFC
                \end{itemize}
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item Security solutions in VFC
                    \end{itemize}
                    & 2019      \\
{[15]}    %\cite{142}
    & VFC environment
        & \ding{51} & \ding{55} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} 
            &   \begin{itemize}
            \item V2V and V2I in VEC
            \item Security and privacy in VEC
                \end{itemize}
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item VFC and VEC comparison
                \item VEC security requirements
                    \end{itemize} 
                    & 2019      \\
{[16]}    %\cite{143}
    & FC in VANET 
        & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} & \ding{55} 
            &   \begin{itemize}
            \item Connecting vehicles to VANET
            \item Security and forensics requirements
                \end{itemize} 
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item Vehicles as Fog nodes
                \item Possible scenarios in VFC
                \item Detection and prevention in VFC
                    \end{itemize}
                    & 2017      \\
{[17]}    %\cite{146} 
    & VFC application  
        & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} & \ding{55} & \ding{55} 
            &   \begin{itemize}
            \item VFC : Video crowd-sourcing as a study case
                \end{itemize} 
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item Security and privacy challenges
                \item Countermeasures for mitigation in VFC
                    \end{itemize} 
                    & 2018      \\
{[18]}    %\cite{149}
    & FC in VANET 
        & \ding{55} & \ding{55} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} 
            &   \begin{itemize}
            \item Integration of FC in VANET
                \end{itemize}   
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item Deployment on vehicles as fog nodes
                \item VFC applications
                    \end{itemize} 
                    & 2017      \\
{[19]}    %\cite{145}
    & VFC challenges 
        & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} 
            &   \begin{itemize}
            \item VFC taxonomy vehicles deployment in VFC
                \end{itemize}  
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item VFC implementation requirements
                \item Detection and prevention in VFC
                    \end{itemize}  
                    & 2020      \\
{[20]}    %\cite{147}   
    & Dissemination of Data in VFC
        & \ding{51} & \ding{55} & \ding{51} & \ding{55} & \ding{55} 
            &   VCC vs VFC in:
                \begin{itemize}
            \item Data Dissemination
            \item Applications
            \item Security threats
                \end{itemize} 
                &   \begin{itemize}
                \item Privacy issues in VFC
                \item Misbehaving detection and prevention solutions
                    \end{itemize} 
                    & 2021      \\
\SetCell{cmd=\settowidth\rotheadsize{Our survey}\rothead} Our survey
    & VFC   
        & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51} & \ding{51}
            &   \begin{itemize}
            \item VFC global architecture
            \item VFC implementation
            \item VFC scenarios
            \item Security and privacy threats
            \item Detection and prevention in VFC
                \end{itemize} 
                &   &           \\
\end{tblr}

\caption{Related Surveys Comparison}
\label{tab: RelatedSurveys}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]